# UITextView is not scrolling within another subview

Tags: objective-c, ios, scroll, uitextview

I have a `UITextView` named `descriptionText`, that I added as a subview to `viewDescription`. Which itself is a subview of `sliderView`:

```
sliderView -> viewDescription -> descriptionText
```

For some reason, the `descriptionText` does NOT scroll. However, if I add it as subview to `sliderView`, it does scroll...

This is how I created the `UITextView`:

```
_descriptionText                    = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 220, 100)];
_descriptionText.text               = @"Some long text here...";
_descriptionText.backgroundColor    = [UIColor clearColor];
_descriptionText.textAlignment      = UITextAlignmentLeft;
_descriptionText.textColor          = [UIColor whiteColor];
_descriptionText.font               = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
_descriptionText.editable           = NO;
```

Note that i've set:

```
_viewDescription.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

How can I get it to work?

Edit 1:
I've also tried all these things but there were no improvements:

```
[_descriptionText setContentSize:CGSizeMake(500, 500)];
[_descriptionText setContentOffset:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
[_descriptionText setOpaque:TRUE];
[_descriptionText setEditable:NO];
[_descriptionText setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
[_descriptionText setScrollEnabled:YES];
[_descriptionText setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Edit 2:
This is _viewDescription:

```
_viewDescription = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( self.frame.size.width + 20, 110, 230, 140)];
```

and this is the custom sliderView:

```
_sliderView = [[PTSlidersDimension alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(350, 270, 390, 250)]
```

Note that PTSliderDimension is a custom class that inherits from UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What frame does your `viewDescription` have? Probably it is smaller than the frame of your `descriptionText`?

(Both `scrollEnabled` and `userInteractionEnabled` is YES by default, so this wont help.)

Comment: The frame of the viewDescription is (20, 110, 230, 140), so it's not smaller than the descriptionText.

Comment: check & show us the `frame`, `bounds` and `userInteractionEnabled` flag on all three views, that are involved. What type is viewDescription, a plain UIView, or a custom view? What is sliderView, and what is its frame?

Comment: So what is `self.frame.size.width` at the point you are initalizing viewDescription? Perhaps its still zero at that point. Where do you create your views? Than your view would be too snall.

Comment: self refers here to _sliderView. I'm creating _viewDescription and _descriptionText in my custom class PTSLidersDimension. _viewDescription is a subview to self and _descriptionText is a subview to _viewDescription. If I change and make _descriptionText a subview for self, then it scrolls, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: `option A)` there is a problem with viewDescription. check userInteractionEnabled and its frame after initialization. `option B)` Your PTSLidersDimension class overwrites the touch handling / hittest methods in any (wrong) way. does it?

Comment: option C) You were right in the first place. _viewDescription is outside it's superview's frame so even though I cans see it, I can't interact with it. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
_descriptionText.scrollEnabled    = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Hermann Klecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854396/hermann-klecker) has mentioned `scrollEnabled` can be used, and also you can try

```
_descriptionText.UserInteractionsEnabled =YES;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
_descriptionText.textAlignment                       =   NSTextAlignmentJustified;
    _descriptionText.showsVerticalScrollIndicator        =   false;
    _descriptionText.selectable                          =   false;
    _descriptionText.editable                            =   false;
```

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer